# PHP Multi Curl User Function Processing just 1 Request at a Time. How to get it to be done in Parallel?

Tags: php, curl

Alright, I have a PHP multi curl class, that is working up until this line...

```
while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->MH)) 
{
    $handle     = $info['handle'];
    $curlInfo   = curl_getinfo($handle);

    $url        = $curlInfo['url'];
    $content    = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);

    //here is where the bottleneck happens
    $this->data[] = call_user_func($this->curl['CALLBACK'], $content, $url, $handle);

    curl_multi_remove_handle($this->MH, $handle);
    curl_close($handle);
}
```

I currently have it set to 20 requests at a time. And when I put in timestamps before and after the call_user_func... I get something where I'm getting the individual times right, as in it takes about .4 seconds to complete the user func on the first request. The problem is, it doesn't do the requests at the same time. The second request will take .4 seconds to complete but it will be .8 seconds of processing time. After 20 requests, it takes like 8 second.

If you want more info, please let me know. Not sure what providing the script for handling the user func would provide as it shouldn't stop the script from running in parallel? Am I missing something here? The script does exactly what I want and it's working, it's just not doing it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pthreads (for threading)

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Or pcntl_fork (for multi-processing)

http://php.net/pcntl_fork

Or alternatively you can make a separate script for doing the curl request and run them in the shell.